# How to split string in group in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, split, substring

i'm amol kadam,I want to know how to split string in two part.My string is in Time format (12:12).& I want to seperate this in hour & minute format.the datatype for all variables are string. for hour variable used strTimeHr & for minute strTimeMin .I tried below code but their was a exception **"Index and length must refer to a location within the string.
Parameter name: length"**

```
                If Not (objDS.Tables(0).Rows(0)("TimeOfAccident") Is Nothing Or objDS.Tables(0).Rows(0)("TimeOfAccident") Is System.DBNull.Value) Then
                    strTime = objDS.Tables(0).Rows(0)("TimeOfAccident") 'strTime taking value 12:12
                    index = strTime.IndexOf(":")                        'index taking value 2  
                    lastIndex = strTime.Length                          'Lastindex taking value 5   

                    strTimeHr = strTime.Substring(0, index)               'strTime taking value 12 correctly
     strTimeMin = strTime.Substring(index + 1, lastIndex)   'BUT HERE IS PROBLEM OCCURE strTimeMin Doesn't taking any value
                    Me.NumUpDwHr.Text = strTimeHr
                    Me.NumUpDwMin.Text = strTimeMin
                End If
```

Comment: What is the datatype of the column "TimeOfAccident"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way (assumming that you can ensure the format) is to use a split:

```
dim strTime as string = objDs.Tables(0).Rows(0).("TimeOfAccident")
dim timeParts() as string =  split(strTime,":")
dim strTimeHr as string = timeParts(0)
dim strTimeMn  as string = timePartS(1)
```

you'll also want some error handling to check for formatting and that the split generates the array with at least two elements and what not.

***EDIT:***  After looking more closely at your code, I see the cause of your error.

You have this code:

```
lastIndex = strTime.Length 
strTimeHr = strTime.Substring(0, index)
strTimeMin = strTime.Substring(index + 1, lastIndex)
```

With that last line giving the error.

The reason that you're getting that error is that strings (and other arrays) in VB.Net are ZERO BASED. Which is why in the strTimeHr field, you're starting at position 0. Length gives you the count, which since the array is zero-based, means the count will be one more than available indexes.

I.e. the last element in a zero based array is the length of the array minus 1.

Therefore, changing your original code to this:

```
lastIndex = strTime.Length  - 1
strTimeHr = strTime.Substring(0, index)
strTimeMin = strTime.Substring(index + 1, lastIndex)
```

will work as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
string s = "12:13";
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(s);

Console.Write(dt.Hour + " " + dt.Minute);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like ([String.Split Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx) )

```
Dim str As String = "12:13"
Dim strHr = str.Split(":")(0)
Dim strMin = str.Split(":")(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the datatype of the column "TimeOfAccident" a `DateTime`? If so, then the simplest solution would be something like:

```
'Using LINQ to convert the value to a nullable datetime.
Dim timeOfAccident As Nullable(Of DateTime) = dt.Rows(0).Field(Of Nullable(Of DateTime))("TimeOfAccident")

If timeOfAccident.HasValue Then
    Me.NumUpDwHr.Text = timeOfAccident.Hour
    Me.NumUpDwMin.Text = timeOfAccident.Minute
End If
```

If the column "TimeOfAccident" is a string, then you can do something like:

```
Dim timeOfAccidentString As String = dt.Rows(0).Field(String)("TimeOfAccident")

If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(timeOfAccidentString) Then
    Dim accidentTime As DateTime = DateTime.Parse(timeOfAccidentString)
    Me.NumUpDwHr.Text = timeOfAccident.Hour
    Me.NumUpDwMin.Text = timeOfAccident.Minute
End If
```